# Meaning of 狂牛 in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 你在說什麼？
>
> 你是又被變種狂牛攻擊喔了喔？

I'm what the second sentence means. It translates literally to something like

> Have you been attacked by a mutant mad cow again?

But I'm sure that's not the actual meaning. I was thinking it might have something to do with mad cow disease, but that doesn't seem quite right either....

Answer (score 3):

In the context "你是又被變種狂牛攻擊喔了喔？", it is basically just a metaphor for "are you out of your mind?", not that a mad cow really exists.

Answer (score 0):

狂牛 means a mad cow or a cow with the mad cow disease. But I don't know what is the meaning of such a sentence. It could literally mean being attacked by a mad cow. Or something related to being mad.